# How can I show a XHTML page in my HOST?

Tags: java, html, web, server, host

i'm new in server-related topics... I want to show my page xhtml from my project Java Enterprise Project with PrimeFaces, I upload my project in a free host for test and know a bite about this.

When I create a .html page in my host folder I can enter without problems and show the page, but with the .xhtml pages from my project nothing happens.

How can i show my project's pages ?.

Comment: if you just change the extension to **.html** it may still work.

Comment: I tried this but do not load either... I don't know if I will must configurate something else on my server page, I configure my DataBase and upload my project.